# invoking wso2 admin services using wsdl2java

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have a web application from which i have to invoke a WSO2 Admin service..
I am following this https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Calling+Admin+Services

When I used wsdl2java , I got a zip file...When i opened it , it has just a pom.xml..
How can i use this? My web app is using Maven itself..But no clue how to use this pom.xml and invoke admin service? How to generate stub out of this pom.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you build it with maven client stubs will be generated. See [1] as a sample. Any way client stubs are already available in nexus for released products.

EX: If I want to use client stubs for ChallengeQuestionManagementAdminService I can do it by adding maven dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.stub</artifactId>
        <version>xxx</version>
</dependency>
```

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/tree/master/service-stubs/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.stub

Comment: Should i import that pom.xml to my project or shud i just build it somewhere else? How can i do it? And do u know the maven command?

Comment: The second case,if i include the dependency,i dont hav to use this pom.xml u.mean?

Comment: mvn clean install / Yes

Comment: Same project or?

Comment: Also i am looking for start,stp,restart of Enterprise integrator..do u know the dependency for it so that i dont hav to generate stubs?

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.stub</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/carbon-platform-integration-utils/tree/master/common-admin-clients